# Install packages (VLC) via USB

Tags: installation, downloads

I want to install VLC to my Ubuntu laptop, which has no connection to the internet. To work around this I want to download it to my Windows machine, copy it to a USB drive and install on my Ubuntu machine. How can I do this?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to install?

Comment: wanting to download apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/vlc –

Comment: To install VLC offline take a look at [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2123834).

Answer (score 3):

You can download the .deb package version  here [vlc .deb package and dependencies](http://packages.debian.org/sid/vlc-nox) either i386 or amd64 on windows.

after that you can transfer by using USB stick and install it to Ubuntu by right click using GDEBI pakage installer in Ubuntu. If there's messages about dependencies not met than you need to download the dependencies and install it manually and it's provided on that website also.

*WARNING all dependencies must be install first until theres no message appear.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to install .exe in ubuntu? . I assume you download a .exe file and you require to install the same on ubuntu.

You can use wine. Check the documentation in the below link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I was wanting to download a ubuntu app
VLC in question. My ubuntu Laptop does not have internet. So I was wanting download on my Windows machine and copy to USB and run the ubuntu laptop.

Comment: @PeteDicker does this solve your problem?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was wanting to download a ubuntu app VLC in question. My ubuntu Laptop does not have internet. So I was wanting download on my Windows machine and copy to USB and run the ubuntu laptop.

Comment: wanting to download 
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/vlc/

Comment: @PeteDicker pls edit your question instead of commenting. It will help others who visit the post. Right now we can assume and provide a possible answer